# Loop "ifelse" including NA

Tags: r

I want to run a loop using `ifelse()` and including `NA` in R. Here is a example of my dataset named `DATA`:

```
[,1]   [,2]    [,3]    [,4]
ID1     NA      NA      NA
ID2     0       0       0
ID3     1       1       1
ID4     0       0       1
ID5     1       1       0
ID6     0       NA      1
ID7     NA      0       0
ID8     NA      1       1
```

Basically, I want to add a new column at the end using these criteria:

- If there is at least one "1" in column 2, 3 or 4 => 1
- If there is NO "1"  in column 2, 3 or 4, but at least one "0" => 0
- If there is only "NA"  in column 2, 3 or 4 => NOTHING

I thought to use something like that, but it doesn't work. It returns:

```
"NA" if there is no "1", but at least one "0", instead of
"NOTHING"
```

**Example for line 6:**

```
*ifelse(any((DATA[6,c(2:4)])==1), "1", ifelse(any((DATA[6,c(2:4)])==0), "0",
"NOTHING"))*
```

I don't really want to return **"NOTHING"**. In reality I want **"NA"**, but to
verify if a "NA" was the result of something that doesn't work, I used
"NOTHING". I also want to loop the whole thing for each line in my data set, but I'm not very good at it either.

Comment: What should your example data look like afterward? also show that "new column"

Comment: Please make your example reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If your problem got solved please [choose an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

```
rowSums.na <-
    function(x, na.rm = T){

        suma <- rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm)
        ind  <- apply(x, 1, function(el){ all(is.na(el)) })

        suma[ind] <- NA

        return(suma)
}

df1$newCol<- +(rowSums.na(df1[,2:4]) > 0)

#> df1$newCol
#[1] NA  0  1  1  1  1  0  1
```

---

- `df1` is your data.
- normal `rowSums`/ `sum` returns 0 when all values are `NA`. A great mistake IMO. Eval:

  1. `rowSums(matrix(NA, 3, 3), na.rm = T)`
  2. `rowSums.na(matrix(NA, 3, 3))`
- `+( ... )` will convert the boolean into a numeric type. run `+( c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) )` in R console.

Comment: I did not know about the use of `+()`.